# How do you do ROI-Pooling on Areas smaller than the target size?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, classification, detection

---

I am currently trying to get the Faster R-CNN network from [here](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF) to work in windows with tensorflow. For that, I wanted to re-implement the ROI-Pooling layer, since it is not working in windows (at least not for me. If you got any tips on porting to windows with tensorflow, I would highly appreciate your comments!). According to [this](https://blog.deepsense.ai/region-of-interest-pooling-explained/) website, what you do is, you take your proposed roi from your feature map and max pool its content to a fixed output size. This fixed output is needed for the following fully connected layers, since they only accept a fixed size input.

---

### The problem now is the follwing:

After conv5_3, the last convolutional layer before roi pooling, the box that results from the region proposal network is mostly 5x5 pixels in size. This is totally fine, since the objects I want to detect usually have dimensions of 80x80 pixels in the original image (downsampling factor due to pooling is 16). However, I now have to max pool an area of 5x5 pixels and ENLARGE it to 7x7, the target size for the ROI-Pooling. My first try by simply doing interpolation did not work. Also, padding with zeros did not work. I always seem to get the same scores for my classes.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? I do not want to change the dimensions of any layer and I know that my trained network in general works because I have the reference implementation running in Linux on my dataset.

Thank you very much for your time and effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now an official TF implementation of Faster-RCNN, and other object detection algorithms, in their [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), you should probably check it out.

If you still want to code it yourself, I wondered exactly the same thing as you and could not find an answer about how you're supposed to do. My three guesses would be:

- interpolation, but it changes the feature values, so it destroys some information...
- Resizing to 35x35 just by copying 7 times each cell and then max-pooling back to 7x7 (you don't have to actually do the resizing and then the pooling , for instance in 1D it basically reduces itself to `output[i]=max(input[floor(i*5/7)], input[ceil(i*5/7)])`, with a similar max over 4 elements in 2D -be careful, I might have forgotten some +1/-1 or something-). I see at least two problems: some values are over-represented, being copied more than others; but worse, some (small) values will not even be copied at all in the output ! (which you should avoid given that you can store more information in the output than in the input)
- Making sure all input feature values are copied at least once exactly in the output, at the best possible place (basically copy `input[i]` to `output[j]` with `j=floor((i+1)*7/5)-1)`). For the remaining spots, either leave a 0 or do interpolation. I would think this solution is the best, maybe with interpolations but I'm really not sure at all.

It looks like [smallcorgi's implementation](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF/blob/master/lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling_op.cc) uses my 2nd solution (without actually resizing, just using max pooling), since it's the same implementation as for the case where the input is bigger than the output.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I checked out the official TF implementations of Faster-RCNN, however i am currently using it with the VGG net which I did not find there. I already tried some of your guesses, especially interpolation (doing a simple resize with bicubic interpolation) and padding with zeros and it works to some extend. It is not perfect, but pretty close. For the interpolation-case you have huge variations since a value of lets say 1.0 surrounded by zeros (which is pretty common due to ReLus) is washed out, resulting into something like 0.4, 0.4 and so on. Padding zeros works best atm

Comment: VGG16 is not there indeed. There is a [procedure to use another feature extractor](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md) though, it may be faster than rewriting the ROI-pooling layer, and has the advantage that you'll be able to compare with other feature extractors easily. Besides, you might want to reconsider your choice of VGG, since [ResNet34 for instance seems to outperform it both in accuracy and speed](https://github.com/jcjohnson/cnn-benchmarks) on some tasks.

Comment: My 3rd solution would avoid this "washing out"; the efficiency of the padding may depend on where you're padding (i.e. it is probably better to do it as I suggest rather than copying the 5x5 input to the topleft of the output and leaving the bottom and right to 0, because my method respects the original topology better)

Comment: VGG is fine at the moment, for now I just want my setup to be running, perfomance comes much later. My setup now runs, a bit worse than the reference Linux version, but within the given limitations. The basic question however remains... What is the roi_pooling doing for patches smaller than the target size... Therefore I cannot mark your answer as "answer", I hope you understand that :/

Comment: Yes I do, don't worry ! But after looking a 2nd time at [the implementation of the linux version you're using](https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF/blob/master/lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling_op.cc) (in particular lines 123 to 182) it does look like they're doing just like my 2nd method (which is actually the same code as for ROIs bigger than the target size)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but i post this answer because it might help others. I have written a code that explains how roi pooling works in different height and width conditions for both pool and region.
you can see the link of the code in github:
https://github.com/Parsa33033/RoiPooling